# how do i call jasper which has sub report via spring boot?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, subreport

I've tried several ways, but haven't found anything that works.

how do i call jasper which has sub report via spring boot ?

my controller

```
@PostMapping(value = "/dataSPM", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String DownloadFileSppLsArsip(@RequestBody Map reqMap, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) {
    Users user = usersService.getUserFromAuthentication(authentication);
    Integer tahun = user.getPegawai().getTahunPegawai();
    Integer id_daerah = user.getDaerah().getIdDaerah();
    Integer id_skpd = user.getSkpd().getIdSkpd();       
    String fileName = "";
    String requestParam = null;
    Long idSpm;
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    JsonNode actualObj;
    idSpm = Long.parseLong(reqMap.get("id").toString());        
    String isIdExist = downloadSpmArsipService.findByIdSpm(idSpm);
    if (isIdExist.equals("0")) {
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.setStatus(400);
        String resp = "{\"status\":\"400\", \"message\":\"id not found\"}";
        return resp;
    }
    fileName = "SPM";
    try {            
        Map<String, Object> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
        InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/spm/spm_already_created1.jrxml");
        JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(inputStream);                            
        map.put("subReport", "subReport.jasper");
        List<DownloadFileSpmArsipDto> listKegiatanSpm = downloadSpmArsipService.listKegiatanSpm(idSpm);     
        List<DownloadFileSpmDto> data1 = downloadSpmService.data1(tahun,id_daerah,id_skpd,idSpm);
        List<DownloadFileSpmDto2> data2 = downloadSpmService.data2(tahun,id_daerah,id_skpd,idSpm);
        JRBeanCollectionDataSource dataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(data2);
        String id_spm= null;
        String tahunAnggaran= null;
        String noSpm= null;
        String namaDaerah= null;
        String namaSkpd= null;
        String bendaharaPihak3= null;
        String noRek= null;
        String namaBank= null;
        String npwp= null;
        String dasarBayar= null;
        String nomorSpp= null;
        String tanggalSpp= null;
        String namaPa= null;
        String nipPa = null;
        try {
            map.put("tahunAnggaran", data1.get(0).getTahunAnggaran());                  
        }catch(Exception e) {                   
            map.put("tahunAnggaran", null);
        }
        try {
            map.put("noSpm", data1.get(0).getNoSpm());
        }catch(Exception e) {                   
            map.put("noSpm", null);
        }
        try {
            map.put("namaDaerah", data1.get(0).getNamaDaerah());
        }catch(Exception e) {                   
            map.put("namaDaerah", null);
        }
        try {
            map.put("namaSkpd", data1.get(0).getNamaSkpd());
        }catch(Exception e) {                   
            map.put("namaSkpd", null);
        }
        try {
            map.put("bendaharaPihak3", data1.get(0).getBendaharaPihak3());
        }catch(Exception e) {                   
            map.put("bendaharaPihak3", null);
        }
        try {
            map.put("noRek", data1.get(0).getNoRek());
        }catch(Exception e) {                   
            map.put("noRek", null);
        }
        try {
            map.put("namaBank", data1.get(0).getNamaBank());
        }catch(Exception e) {                   
            map.put("namaBank", null);
        }               
        try {
            map.put("npwp", data1.get(0).getNpwp());
        }catch(Exception e) {                   
            map.put("npwp", null);
        }
        try {
            map.put("dasarBayar", data1.get(0).getDasarBayar());
        }catch(Exception e) {                   
            map.put("dasarBayar", null);
        }
        try {
            map.put("npwp", data1.get(0).getNpwp());
        }catch(Exception e) {                   
            map.put("npwp", null);
        }
        try {
            map.put("nomorSpp", data1.get(0).getNomorSpp());
        }catch(Exception e) {                   
            map.put("nomorSpp", null);
        }
        try {
            map.put("tanggalSpp", data1.get(0).getTanggalSpp());
        }catch(Exception e) {                   
            map.put("tanggalSpp", null);
        }
        try {
            map.put("namaPa", data1.get(0).getNamaPa());
        }catch(Exception e) {                   
            map.put("namaPa", null);
        }
        try {
            map.put("nipPa", data1.get(0).getNipPa());
        }catch(Exception e) {                   
            map.put("nipPa", null);
        }
        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, map , dataSource);
        List<JasperPrint> jasperPrintList = new ArrayList<JasperPrint>();
        jasperPrintList.add(jasperPrint);
        JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
        OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
        exporter.setExporterInput(SimpleExporterInput.getInstance(jasperPrintList));
        exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(out));
        SimplePdfExporterConfiguration configuration = new SimplePdfExporterConfiguration();
        exporter.setConfiguration(configuration);
        response.setContentType("application/x-download");
        response.addHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName + ".pdf");
        response.addHeader("filename",fileName+".pdf");
        exporter.exportReport();
    } catch (JRException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.setStatus(400);
        String resp = "{\"status\":\"400\", \"message\":\"something when wrong\"}";
        return resp;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        e.printStackTrace();
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.setStatus(400);
        String resp = "{\"status\":\"400\", \"message\":\"something when wrong\"}";
        return resp;
    }
    response.setStatus(200);
    return "";
}
```

in my main report tag subreport like this

```
<subreport>
                <reportElement x="9" y="367" width="291" height="130" uuid="496ae76c-1b80-49fc-930c-dc39ec3bd57e"/>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{subReport}]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
```

and the jrxml/jasper is in same folder

if I hit endpoint, spring error like this..
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Resource not found at: subReport.jasper.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the path to your subreport the right way. As you're using the classloader, it should be possible to use the relative path.

Instead of using:

```
map.put("subReport", "subReport.jasper");
```

you'd have to use

```
map.put("subReport", "./subReport.jasper");
```